# importing pywinauto on XP vs 7

Tags: python, windows, virtual-machine, pywinauto

I can't import `pywinauto` on XP.

I have a computer running window 7 and a VM running XP. Both of these have almost identical versions of Python.

Here is a picture of differences between the Python27 folders in each environment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao4R7.png

It seems that these are inconsequential differences, especially when it comes to the package in question.

If I try to `import pywinauto` on the XP VM I get the following:

```
>>> import pywinauto.controls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import findwindows
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 37, in <module>
    import controls
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 33,in <module>
    import win32_controls
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\win32_controls.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pywinauto import win32functions
ImportError: cannot import name win32functions
>>>
```

I have not tried to re-install `pywinauto` or `pywin32`. Before I try that, I just want to know if there are any issues with pywinauto between XP and 7? Or between native windows and a VM?

Comment: Please, specify Python2.X 32 or 64bit? pywinauto has problems with some structures size under Python 64bit. I successfully use Python2.7 32bit + pywinauto on Wondows 7 64bit.

Comment: They are both 32 bit 2.7.  I'm going to answer my own question, I would love it if you took a look at it and tell me what I did, I have no idea why it works, but it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out, although I have no idea why. My question was what I though was the root cause of my original problem which was that I got

```
sre_constants.error nothing to repeat
```

when I tried to compile my program in the XP virtual environment. The cause of this was in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\tests\asianhotkey.py` at line 110.

```
_asianHotkeyRE = re.compile (r"""
    \(&.\)      # the hotkey
    (
        (\t.*)|     # tab, and then anything
        #(\\t.*)|   # escaped tab, and then anything
        (\(.*\)     # anything in brackets
    )|
    \s*|            # any whitespace
    :|              # colon
    (\.\.\.)|       # elipsis
    >|              # greater than sign
    <|              # less than sign
    (\n.*)          # newline, and then anything
    \s)*$""", re.VERBOSE)
```

I couldn't even run this in its own script in my virtual XP environment. It would run if I either removed the `*` in either one of these lines

```
\s*|            # any whitespace
```

or

```
\s)*$""", re.VERBOSE)
```

I have no idea why that was the case, just experimental outcomes.

Anyway, as far as I could tell the variable `_asianHotkeyRE` is only used once in this whole package; at line (133) of this same file:

```
found = _asianHotkeyRE.search(text)
```

So I changed those two groups of code to

```
pattern = r"""
    \(&.\)      # the hotkey
    (
        (\t.*)|     # tab, and then anything
        #(\\t.*)|   # escaped tab, and then anything
        (\(.*\)     # anything in brackets
    )|
    \s*|            # any whitespace
    :|              # colon
    (\.\.\.)|       # elipsis
    >|              # greater than sign
    <|              # less than sign
    (\n.*)          # newline, and then anything
    \s)*$"""
```

and

```
 found = re.search(pattern,text)
```

Something about using regular expression compiling didn't like the formatting of this pattern.  Maybe the version of `re` that is installed on that virtual machine isn't up to date or something?

So long story short, it's fixed. I don't know why and I would love it if someone could try to reproduce the issue using their own virtual environments of any kind.